# Problem setting up squidanalyzer

Tags: server, 16.04, apache2

I'm having a problem setting up squidanalyzer on my Ubuntu 16.04 server.

I have download and installed squidanalyzer and installed it using perl

What I'm struggling with is how to setup apache so I can see the reports from squidanalyzer. My server doesn't have a GUI so I've been trying to browse to the site using `http://ipaddress/squidreport` but no luck.

Here is my squidanalyzer.config file for Apache

```
<VirtualHost *> 
Alias /squidreport /var/www/squidanalyzer
    <Directory /var/www/squidanalyzer>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file

Add:

```
    Alias /squidreport /var/www/html/squidanalyzer
    <Directory /var/www/html/squidanalyzer>
        Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews -Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1  
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

My web directory is /var/www/html,  I guess yours is /var/www/

Then you need to generate the reports by running:
/usr/local/bin/squid-analyzer

That will generate your index.html page.
Without that, squidanalyzer won't work

You can add the above command to a daily cronjob.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Squidanalyzer by default is not ready for recent Ubuntu. You need to:

1. add "+" in front of FollowSymLinks and MultiViews in `apache2.conf`, otherwise Apache doesn't start with "-Indexes", as it is in "make install" comment
   `Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews`
2. correct the path to Squid `access.log` in `/etc/squidanalyzer/squidanalyzer.conf` from `/var/log/squid3/access.log` (old location) to the new location: `/var/log/squid/access.log` Without that the script stops and you don't have index.html file to see anything.
3. change in `apache2.conf` under `<Directory /var/www/html/squidanalyzer>` from `Allow from 127.0.0.1` to `Allow from 192.168.1.0/24` or other ip/network you want to connect from to see the stats (not only localhost).

While you do that, you can run `sudo /usr/local/bin/squid-analyzer` and add `0 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/squid-analyzer > /dev/null 2>&1` to your cron.

The project is great anyway.